# Wifi triangulation on iOS 4.2.1 and current location on different iOS simulators

Tags: iphone, ipod, triangulation

I have iPod Touch 2G, iOS 4.2.1 and I'm not able to determine the device's location (using Wifi triangulation) after software update from iOS 3.2.
My code:

```
-(IBAction) naitapraeguneasukoht: (id) sender 
{
     CLLocation*location=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:57.797944 longitude:25.04858];
     MKCoordinateRegion region = {{0.0f, 0.0f}, {0.0f, 0.0f}};
     region.center = location.coordinate;
     region.span.longitudeDelta = 1.0f;
     region.span.latitudeDelta = 3.8f;

     [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
     [location release];

     self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
     locationManager.delegate = self;
     locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers;
     [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void) locationManager: (CLLocationManager *) manager didFailWithError: (NSError *) error 
{
    NSString *teade = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Ei õnnestunud asukohta tuvastada"];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:trade delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [teade release];
    [alert release];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.005f;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.005f;
    region.center=newLocation.coordinate;
    region.span=span;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
}
```

I get an error message that it's not possible to determine the location. Location services is definately on.

The iOS 4.2 simulator gives me my correct location, but iOS 5.0 simulator gives me Cupertino. Why's that so and why doesn't it work on my device?